# How to run sqlplus centOS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, oracle, centos

I am install Oracle Instant Client: Basic, SDK and SQL*Plus packages v 12.1.0.1 for `gem "ruby-oci8"` than i realize that i need use Oracle Instant Client v 10.2.0.5. I remove ver. 12 first (rpm -e) than i dowload zip file 10.2.0.5 and unzip the packages as follows:

```
mkdir /opt
mkdir /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle
unzip path/to/instantclient-basic-OS-VERSION.zip
unzip path/to/instantclient-sdk-OS-VERSION.zip
unzip path/to/instantclient-sqlplus-OS-VERSION.zip
```

after that i set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/"
export SQLPATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/"
export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251"
export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle/
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/instantclient_10_2/
```

my env:

```
HOSTNAME=srvwe041
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
SSH_CLIENT=10.14.64.103 49242 22
OLDPWD=/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/instantclient_10_2
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy.rccf.ru:8080
USER=schechaev
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/schechaev
PWD=/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SQLPATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2
KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1252_VhmQZQ
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HOME=/root
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=schechaev
CVS_RSH=ssh
SSH_CONNECTION=10.14.64.103 49242 10.15.159.233 22
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/bin/env
```

It is my /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/ ls:

```
BASIC_README        libclntsh.so.10.1  libsqlplus.so             orai18n.jar
classes12.jar       libheteroxa10.so   libsqora.so.10.1          sdk
genezi              libnnz10.so        ODBC_IC_Readme_Unix.html  sqlplus
glogin.sql          libocci.so.10.1    ODBCRelnotesJA.htm        SQLPLUS_README
instantclient_10_2  libociei.so        ODBCRelnotesUS.htm
JDBC_README         libocijdbc10.so    odbc_update_ini.sh
libclntsh.so        libsqlplusic.so    ojdbc14.jar
```

But whan i type `sqlplus` i have error:

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

How to resols this isue?

Comment: You probably need to set `ORACLE_HOME` to your Oracle software directory.

Answer (score 2):

After reboot centOS `reboot now` sqlplus is work ))):

```
 [root@srvwe041 instantclient_10_2]#./sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Thu Oct 31 11:44:44 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Enter user-name:
```

It Is miracle!

But before it i set vim ~/bash_profile

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle/
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/instantclient_10_2/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/"
export SQLPATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/"
export NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251"
```